# String interpolation. Find the objects prop that matches the string inside [...] and replace with the value of the prop

Tags: javascript, regex, function, object

I am working on a function that finds the objects prop that matches the string inside [...] and replaces with the value of the prop.. it also has to ignore any strings inside of [[...]] and remove the outer square brackets

For example

interpolate('Hello [name] [[author]]', {name: 'foo', author: 'bar'})

Would result in 'Hello foo [author]'

Here is my code so far

```
const person1 = { name: 'John', author: 'John & John'};
const person2 = { name: 'Jill', author: 'Jk Jowling' };
const person3 = { name: 'Jack', author: 'Wacko Jacko'};

const str1 = 'Hello [name] [[author]]';

// Find the objects prop that matches the string inside [...] and replace with the value of the prop
// Ignore the values inside double brackets [[...]]


const interpolate = (string, obj) => {
// Throw errors if incorrect arguments are passed in
if (!string || typeof string !== 'string') {
    throw new Error(`"string" is required`);
}

if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    throw new Error(`"object" is required`);
}

Object.keys(obj).map((value) => {
    string
    .split(' ')
    .indexOf(`[${value}]`) === 1 || string.indexOf(`[[${value}]]`) === -1
  ? console.log(string.replaceAll(`[${value}]`, obj[value])) 
  : console.log(`One or more unidentifiers found in String: ${string}`)
})


// Working better but still need to work on conditionals

// Removed RegEx

// Used replaceAll to target multiple [string]


};

interpolate(str1, person1);
interpolate(str1, person2);
interpolate(str1, person3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the regex

```
(?<!\[)\[([^[\]]*)](?!\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yljgm1/1)

This will get all the strings with `[]` which are not preceded by a `[` and followed by a `]`. The `([^[\]]*)` part will get the string inside `[]` to a capturing group. You can use the second parameter from the [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to access this and get the value from the object.

Replace the matched string with the property from the object

```js
function interpolate (string, obj) {
   return string.replace(/(?<!\[)\[([^[\]]*)](?!\])/g, (m, p1) => obj[p1] ?? '')
}

const str = 'Replace name: [name] but not [[author]]. Replace this with author: [author]';

console.log(
  interpolate(str, { name: 'John', author: 'John & John'})
)

console.log(
  interpolate(str, { name: 'Jill', author: 'Jk Jowling' })
)
```